# Hoverintent for Prototype / Scriptaculous

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, scriptaculous, hoverintent

Recently came across the [HoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) for jQuery.   It acts like a regular mouseover or hover observer, but waits to fire the action until/if the mouse slows down or rests.  With tuning, it makes for interfaces that feel more human responsive.

The website I'd like to use it on is committed to a Prototype / Scriptaculous framework, and I'd very much like to not add jQuery to the mix.

Is there an equivalent way of achieving this behavior in Prototype / Scriptaculous, either natively or with an additional script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://spuntinu.net/insert-a-delay-on-large-drop-down-menu-with-prototype/ used to do the trick.

Now, see http://backfromcamden.net/insert-a-delay-on-large-drop-down-menu-with-prototype/
[Thanks, Jonathan Day]

Comment: link is 404. try this instead: http://backfromcamden.net/insert-a-delay-on-large-drop-down-menu-with-prototype/

Comment: Both links are now invalid.